# SSRS report builder - Failed to preview report

Tags: exception, reporting-services, reportbuilder

One of the user is trying to run a report through SSRS report builder from his computer. The same report would work through the SSRS reports website. But when he runs from his computer it fails. On the Report builder - test connections on Data source succeeds.

It errors out with "microsoft.reportingservices.diagnostics.utilities.accessdeniedException". 
Here is a screenshot. The results Google produced did not help.

```
http://screencast.com/t/nlxsprwQBefw
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to necro-post, but I had the same issue and @djangojazz's answer is almost correct, there are actually 3 steps:

1. Log in to https://servername/reports as an administrator
2. Click the gear in the top right > site settings > security tab.  Add the user as a "System User"
3. Click browse, and at the root level click "Manage folder", add the user to all roles.

After doing these steps on SQL Standard 2016 (version 13.0.4422.0) / Report Builder 3 (version 14.0.609.142), the user was then able to preview reports without having to give them full server admin rights / etc.

Answer (score 1):

Users needs to be a member of permission: "Report Builder" or "Content Manager" under their security context of the SSRS site:

1. HAVE AN ADMIN THAT SET UP SSRS: Go to http:// (servername)/Reports  (default location of SSRS landing page.
2. Click on the 'Folder Settings' in the ribbon of the 'Home' directory or directory user is trying to reach.
3. Click 'Security'
4. Click 'New Role Assignment'
5. Add users with (Domain)(user) context and assign them 'Report Builder' or 'Content Manager' if they don't exist.
6. Have user try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this a few times. Didn't help :(

Comment: You may also try to elevate that user under 'Site Settings' too to an admin.  But that should not be the case.  If the person is accessing it via the web and then hitting report builder, the dll that downloaded may also be bad.

Answer (score 1):

same problem happened to me, my solution is to run IE as administrator and then after that I can run or preview the report again.